# Python extension object and wx custom events initialization

Tags: python, c++, shared-libraries, wxwidgets

I have the following scenario:

1. An application written in C++/Wxwidgets 2.8 and embedded python interpreter.
2. An extension for python made as shared object.

These two components shares a few wxwidgets custom events as following

```
DEFINE_LOCAL_EVENT_TYPE(ID_PRE_PROCESS_X_COMMAND);
DEFINE_LOCAL_EVENT_TYPE(ID_POST_PROCESS_X_COMMAND);
DEFINE_LOCAL_EVENT_TYPE(ID_PRE_PROCESS_Y_COMMAND);
DEFINE_LOCAL_EVENT_TYPE(ID_POST_PROCESS_Y_COMMAND);
```

I launch the application and then import the extension module, upon importing the module these event types are updated to have newer IDs.

Example :

1. launched app with ID_PRE_PROCESS_X_COMMAND = 10304
2. importing python extension module, updates ID_PRE_PROCESS_X_COMMAND = 10308

Here is the output of watch point inside GDB on ID_PRE_PROCESS_X_COMMAND

```
#0  __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (__initialize_p=1, __priority=65535) at Runner.cpp:8
#1  0x00007fffe1ad02d9 in global constructors keyed to Runner.cpp(void) () at Runner.cpp:73
#2  0x00007fffe1b91fe6 in __do_global_ctors_aux () from /path/to/Dependcy.so    
#3  0x00007fffe1aacb23 in _init () from /path/to/Dependcy.so
#4  0x00007fffe1df8888 in ?? () from /path/to/ExtensionModule.so
#5  0x00007ffff7deb1e8 in call_init () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#6  0x00007ffff7deb317 in _dl_init_internal () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#7  0x00007ffff7def636 in dl_open_worker () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#8  0x00007ffff7deae76 in _dl_catch_error () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#9  0x00007ffff7deee2b in _dl_open () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#10 0x00007ffff6017f9b in dlopen_doit () from /lib64/libdl.so.2
#11 0x00007ffff7deae76 in _dl_catch_error () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#12 0x00007ffff601833c in _dlerror_run () from /lib64/libdl.so.2
#13 0x00007ffff6017f01 in dlopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 () from /lib64/libdl.so.2
#14 0x00007ffff6571064 in _PyImport_GetDynLoadFunc (fqname=<optimized out>, shortname=0x7fffe4085d50 "ExtensionModule", 
    pathname=0x7fffe4086d60 "/path/to/ExtensionModule.so", fp=0x7fffe40374a0) at Python/dynload_shlib.c:130
```

The question is how to prevent multiple initialization of these events so their numbers are constant even after loading the extension module.

---

## Edit 1

After a bit of debugging I found that `DEFINE_LOCAL_EVENT_TYPE(ID_PRE_PROCESS_X_COMMAND);` gets expanded to `const wxEventType ID_PRE_PROCESS_X_COMMAND = wxNewEventType()`

Where `wxNewEventType` is defined as following inside wxWdigets

```
int wxNewEventType()
{
    // MT-FIXME
    static int s_lastUsedEventType = wxEVT_FIRST; // wxEvt_FIRST = 10000

    return s_lastUsedEventType++;
}
```

As Runner.cpp as translation unit is used in shared object and the main application, its global constructors are called twice leading to wxNewEventType called twice changing the value of Event Types.

I am not sure if there is a way to prevent this, or I will try to move events somewhere else.

Comment: did you look at the event sample to see how its done? And if you did - who is changing the ID - python or C++? BTW, the python extension also written in wxPython/Phoenix or its a different thing?

Comment: Python extension is written using the C API of Python.
Simply the ID is created twice, one time upon the application start and the another when loading the python module (shared object )
Would you elaborate which event sample you mean ?

Comment: I'm talking about wxWidgets event sample that come with the library.  Get the sources and check how it is done. I also have another question - why do you need to create the ID twice?

Comment: @Igor, I don't create the ID twice.. They are different 4 IDs.

Comment: @Igor, I rechecked the event sample, it's too trivial.

Comment: you are. As you note in the edit you initialize the id twice. Look at the sample code and see where all those macro are declared/defined and just follow the same pattern. Basically you need the DEFINE_LOCAL_EVENT_TYPE to be implemented in one place - where you handle the event. But you can do DECLARE_LOCAL_EVENT_TYPE as many times as you need.

Comment: the sample code is simple, but it should serve the purpose of showing how to design the code to avoid this type of errors.